# Como adicionar uma borda em uma imagem com C#

Tags: c#

Gostaria de pegar uma imagem e adicionar uma borda na parte superior da imagem(BMP).
Pelo que eu pesquisei preciso

1. carregar a imagem em um objecto
2. criar um objeto retângulo
3. adicionar o retângulo na imagem

mas eu nunca trabalhei com imagem no C# :(

Exemplo:
Essa imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

para ficar assim

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Veja se isso pode te ajudar http://stackoverflow.com/a/14593261/2221388

Comment: `WinForms` ou `WPF`?

Comment: Estou fazendo um serviço de windows, este método vou colocar em uma biblioteca.

Comment: @PabloVargas este exemplo a borda sobrepõe  a imagem, eu quero adicionar uma borda.

Comment: @Fellipe Você quer inserir essa borda "dentro" da imagem? Ou seja, editar o próprio arquivo bmp?

Comment: @ismael era uma opção, mas decidi criar um outro arquivo concatenando duas imagens. Deixei uma borda padrão para ser adicionada nas imagens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver este problema concatenando duas imagens.

```
            Image principal = Image.FromFile(@"ImagemPrincipal.jpg");
            Image logo = Image.FromFile(@"ImagemHeader.jpg");

            int imagemSaida_Width = principal.Width;
            int imagemSaida_Height = principal.Height + logo.Height;

            var imagemSaida = new Bitmap(imagemSaida_Width, imagemSaida_Height);

            using (principal)
            {
                using (imagemSaida)
                {
                    using (var canvas = Graphics.FromImage(imagemSaida))
                    {

                        canvas.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                        // Definir plano de funda do arquivo de saida como Branco
                        canvas.Clear(Color.White);

                        // Adicionar o logo no arquivo de saida
                        canvas.DrawImage(logo, 0, 0);

                        // Adidionar principal no arquivo de saida
                        canvas.DrawImage(exame, 0, logo.Height);
                        canvas.Save();
                    }
                    imagemSaida.Save("ImagePrincipalComLogo.jpg");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, seria só alterar os tamanhos dos px da border não?!

border-image-width: 10px 10px  10px 10px;
          (cima) (direita) (baixo)  (esquerda)